# What does determinant equals to one mean in the transformation matrix?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

When the determinant of transformation matrix is 1, what does it mean? Transformation can be orthogonal or perspective.

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Orientation_of_a_basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The determinant gives the scaling factor and the orientation induced by the mapping.

It is an orthogonal projection because it does not change the scale of things, no matter how close or far away.